# About derived divided power envelope

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, derived-algebraic-geometry, crystalline-cohomology

Assume $A$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$-algebra with ideal $I$ and $A,A/I$ are $p$-torsionfree.

In this [survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.00668.pdf), Akhil Mathew defines the *derived divided power envelope* $LD_I(A)$ in Construction 7.15, after that he claims under the assumption that $A/p$ has flat
Frobenius and the $p$-completely flatness of $L_{(A/I)/A}$, we can
say $LD_I(A)$ is discrete and is the subring of $A\otimes \mathbb{Q}$
generated by divided powers, which is the classical divided power envelope.

I failed to find a clear proof of this claim in papers cited in the survey. I think the flatness of $L_{(A/I)/A}$ is called "quasiregular" in the
sense of Quillen, but Lemma 3.42 of Bhatt's [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.6560.pdf) only shows the result
under a "Koszul-regular" assumption.

After more searching, I find that a proof has
already written down in a recent paper: see Corollary 3.68 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.02921.pdf But it's in a rather general context and the
argument is convoluted.

My question: is there a more
direct proof of this claim in the literature?

Comment: I think that Ahkil Mathew already sketched an argument: you have the conjugate filtration on the "derived" PD-envelope (after mod p) of which the associated graded are expressed in terms of Frobenius twists of exterior powers of the cotangent complex, which are concentrated in degree 0 and flat over the Frobenius twist, thus the derived PD-envelope is also concentrated in degree 0 by, say, Lem 3.69 of the linked article.

Comment: And the linked article is simply a detailed exposition of such an argument (which was indicated in Bhatt's article), trying to lay down the foundation which the author did not find in the literature.